# Second set of text not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function(e) {
  /** Make div draggable **/
  $('<div />', {
    class: 'ui-widget-content',
    appendTo: '.container4',
    draggable: {
      containment: 'parent',
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
      }
    }
  });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text1', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('.item1').find('.edit_text1').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text1", function() {
  return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function() {
  var editingText = $('.edit_text1:visible');
  if (editingText.length) {
    editingText.hide();
    editingText.closest('.item1').find('.text1').text($(editingText).val()).show();
  }
});


var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
    $(element).addClass('item1' + count);
    count++;
    $(element).on('click', function() {
      selectedDraggable = $(this);
    })
  }
};


var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.items1 = ko.observableArray();
  self.textContent1 = ko.observable('');
  self.init = function() {
    self.items1([]);
  }
  self.remove = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    self.items1.remove(item);
  }
  self.addNew1 = function() {
    self.items1.push(self.textContent1());
    self.textContent1('');
  }
  self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());



$("#fss").change(function() {
  selectedDraggable.css("font-family", $(this).val());
});



$("#size1").change(function() {
  selectedDraggable.css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});


$('.fooo').click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.css("color", $(this).attr('data-color'));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rotateButton1").click(function() {
    var x = $("#rotateInput").val();
    selectedDraggable.css('transform', 'rotate(' + x + 'deg)');

  });
});

var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText1').click(function(e) {
  /** Make div draggable **/
  $('<div />', {
    class: 'ui-widget-content',
    appendTo: '.container',
    draggable: {
      containment: 'parent',
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
      }
    }
  });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function() {
  return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function() {
  var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
  if (editingText.length) {
    editingText.hide();
    editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
  }
});


var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
    $(element).addClass('item' + count);
    count++;
    $(element).on('click', function() {
      selectedDraggable = $(this);
    })
  }
};


var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray();
  self.textContent = ko.observable('');
  self.init = function() {
    self.items([]);
  }
  self.remove = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    self.items.remove(item);
  }
  self.addNew = function() {
    self.items.push(self.textContent());
    self.textContent('');
  }
  self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());



$("#fs").change(function() {
  selectedDraggable.css("font-family", $(this).val());
});



$("#size").change(function() {
  selectedDraggable.css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});


$('.foo').click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.css("color", $(this).attr('data-color'));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rotateButton").click(function() {
    var x = $("#rotateInput").val();
    selectedDraggable.css('transform', 'rotate(' + x + 'deg)');

  });
});
$("#curveup").click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.circleType({
    fitText: true,
    radius: 100
  });
});

$("#demo1").circleType({
  radius: 100
});

$("#curvedown").click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.circleType({
    fitText: true,
    radius: 100,
    dir: -1
  });
});
$("#demo2").circleType({
  radius: 100,
  dir: -1
});


$("#circle").click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.circleType();
});

$("#demo3").circleType();
$("#curveup1").click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.circleType({
    fitText: true,
    radius: 100
  });
});

$("#demo4").circleType({
  radius: 100
});

$("#curvedown1").click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.circleType({
    fitText: true,
    radius: 100,
    dir: -1
  });
});
$("#demo5").circleType({
  radius: 100,
  dir: -1
});


$("#circle1").click(function() {
  selectedDraggable.circleType();
});

$("#demo6").circleType();

$("#show_front").click(function() {
  $(".frontdiv").toggle();
  $(".backdiv").hide();
});

$("#show_back").click(function() {
  $(".backdiv").toggle();
  $(".frontdiv").hide();
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.item1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.preview-area {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
}
.preview-area1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
}
.edit_text {
  display: none;
}
.edit_text1 {
  display: none;
}
.fix_backround {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.fix_backround1 {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.backdiv {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Will stretch to specified width/height */
  background-size: 490px 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.container1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container2 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container3 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container4 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 220px;
  height: 290px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<div class="overall">
  <div class="backdiv">
    <center>Back</center>
    <div class="container3" style=" float: left;">


      <p align="center">
        <textarea data-bind="value: textContent1" Placeholder="Type text to append" rows="4" cols="21"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: addNew1">Create</button>
      </p>





      </p>



      <div id="curveup1">
        <p class="cup1" id="demo4">Curve Down.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="curvedown1">
        <p class="cud1" id="demo5">Curve UP.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="circle1">
        <p class="circl1" id="demo6">Circle Text.</p>
      </div>


      <p align="center">
        <button type="button" id="remove1" class="remover1">Remove Text</button>
      </p>
      </center>
      <p align="center"></p>
    </div>

    <center>
      <div id="box1" class="container4" style="float:left;">
        <div id="boxes1" class="container5" style="float:center;">
          <div data-bind="foreach:items1" class="fix_backround1">
            <div class="item1" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">

              <center><span class="text1" data-bind="text:$data"></span>
                <input class="edit_text1" />
              </center>





            </div>
          </div>
          <span id="image" class="preview-area1"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="frontdiv">
    <center>Front</center>
    <div class="container1" style=" float: left;">


      <p align="center">
        <textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append" rows="4" cols="21"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: addNew">Create</button>
      </p>
      <center>
        <div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
          <input type="file" class="dimmy" id="image-input" multiple />
        </div>
      </center>

      <center>
        <div id="curveup">
          <p class="cup" id="demo1">Curve Down.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="curvedown">
          <p class="cud" id="demo2">Curve UP.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="circle">
          <p class="circl" id="demo3">Circle Text.</p>
        </div>


        <p align="center">
          <button type="button" id="remove" class="remover">Remove Text</button>
        </p>
      </center>
      <p align="center"></p>
    </div>

    <center>
      <div id="box" class="container" style="float:left;">
        <div id="boxes" class="container5" style="float:center;">
          <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
            <div class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">

              <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span>
                <input class="edit_text" />
              </center>

            </div>
          </div>
          <span id="image" class="preview-area"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div class="container2" style=" float: left;">
    <button type="button" id="show_front">Display Front</button>
    <button type="button" id="show_back">Display Back</button>

  </div>
```

this is difficult to explain i have a toggle that allows me to switch from one div to another but when i do this the second (backdiv) will not allow me to display any text if i move the backdiv to the beginning i will let me input text but the other div will not input any text i tried many things i tried combining them and it doesn't work i checked my code and everything seems to be correct i also did individual div on a single page and it works great but when i put them in the same page one cancels the other what can i do?

Comment: Add only the shortest code necessary to reproduce you problem

Comment: This is my shortest code I can't make Iit any shorter

Comment: @maldalin ivascu why does the first div cancels the second one

Comment: what first div,what second div?

Comment: Frontdiv  and backdiv